# Sharing file on google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am developing android app which share the content to friends using Google Drive.So is it possible to share file programatically using google drive in android?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Drive Sharing is accomplished using Google Drive API for Java as follows

googleDrive.permissions.insert(Permission);

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible, if you don't include a standard share functionality in your app but want to upload specifically to Google Drive you are going to have to use the Google Drive APIs. It's a little more complex so I'm not going to post a full solution but I will show you the important parts. I suggest you take a look at one of these example projects:

- [Google Docs Upload Example](https://github.com/mendhak/googledocs-upload-sample)
- [Google Drive Quickstart Example](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java)

But anyway here are the important parts:

First you have to create an API client which will look something like this:

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);

// Add Drive API
mGoogleApiClient.addApi(Drive.API);

// Set Scope
mGoogleApiClient.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);

// Add required callbacks
mGoogleApiClient.addConnectionCallbacks(this);
mGoogleApiClient.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this);

// Build client
mGoogleApiClient.build();
```

And with this API client you can upload/download/move/copy/delete files and folders etc.

Uploading a file would look something like this:

```
Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {

        // Check for success
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }

        // Upload file
        OutputStream outputStream = result.getContents().getOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
        try {
            outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.", e);
        }

        // Set meta data
        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder();
        metadataChangeSet.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
        metadataChangeSet.setTitle("Android Photo.png");
        metadataChangeSet.build();

        // Create file chooser
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi.newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                .setInitialContents(result.getContents())
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);

        // Show file chooser
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.", e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i just try quickstart sample i have some error please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636659/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-play-serivces-libwithout-supporting-ja please help me

Comment: Where is outputStream used/referenced? I.e. how is the file you want to upload connected to the newCreateFileActivityBuilder()?

Comment: @powder366 what do you mean?

Comment: Found this resource which helped me: https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java